# How was the $\Gamma _\mu$ be used as a gauge condition in the Generalized Harmonic formulation $R_{\mu\nu}$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge, harmonics

I'm watching a video([ICTP-SAIFR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ct6pTfYlbZ8) Numerical Relativity by Sascha Husa) where he mentioned that

> $$R_{\mu\nu} 
> =-\frac{1}{2} 
> g^{\lambda \rho} g_{\mu\nu,\lambda \rho}
> +\nabla_{ (\mu }\Gamma_{\nu)}
> +\Gamma_{\lambda} {}^\eta {}_\mu g_{\eta \delta} g^{\lambda \rho} \Gamma_{\rho} {}^\delta {}_\nu
> +2\Gamma_\delta {}^\lambda {}_\eta g^{\delta\rho}
> g_{\lambda( \mu } \Gamma_{\nu) } {}^\eta {}_\rho$$
> could be treated such that "the contracted Christoffel symbol was the source term for the wave operator on the coordinate", where $R_{\mu\nu}$ could be solved through the Maxwell like gauge potential, by imposing the gauges
> $\Gamma_\mu = \Gamma_{\mu \alpha}^\alpha$
> as a given function, then
> $\Box x^\mu = \Gamma^\mu $
> corresponds to evolution equations for $\alpha,\beta$,
> $$\partial_t \alpha - \alpha_{,a} \beta ^a =\alpha^2 (K-n_\nu \Gamma^\nu)$$
> $$\partial_t \beta^a - \beta^a {}_{,b} \beta^b =
> \alpha^2 (\gamma^a -D^a \log \alpha - h^a {}_\nu \Gamma^\nu)$$
> and introduces constraints
> $ C^\mu \equiv \Gamma^\mu -\Box x^\mu $ and $C^\mu =0$

But I'm not sure why the connection and its contraction could be treated as a gauge field. I thought the Christoffel symbol(principle connection) was used in the lie derivatives to tell how to change from charts, where the space time curvature is deterministically constrained through the stress tensor. How could the contraction of Christoffel symbol $\Gamma_\mu$ be used as a gauge? Where was the degree of freedom introduced/ allowed ?

How was the $\Gamma _\mu$ be used as a gauge condition in the Generalized Harmonic formulation $R_{\mu\nu}$